Copy to Clipboard Issue - Running Selenium Headless Browser on GitHub Actions
Here is my code for adding to clipboard:
def add_to_clipboard(text):
     try:
         pyperclip.copy(text)  # Copy the text to the clipboard using pyperclip
     except Exception as e:
         print(f"An error occurred while copying to clipboard: {e}")

When I run this locally, it runs perfect on a non-headless browser. However, when I go to run this through GitHub actions, it does not work because GitHub actions seems to only run on a headless browser.
How should I address this issue?
Is it easy to make my code run on GitHub Actions?
Should I use something besdies GitHub Actions?
Error Code from GitHub Below:
An error occurred while copying to clipboard: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
    For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error 
(Session info: chrome-headless-shell=124.0.6367.60)

I tried to copy a list in python to be able to paste the data in a website using Selenium. My solution runs locally, however, it does not run on GitHub actions because it is a headless browser.
I need to make the clipboard contents equal to a list so that I can paste tabular data on the page.

An alternative approach to the problem can be the usage of JS Clipboard APIs. You can use writeText() to add the list to the clipboard and use readText() to write the clipboard's content to the input element.
navigator.clipboard.writeText('Here, you add the content which will be copied!')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Text copied to clipboard');
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error copying text to clipboard:', error);
  });

The copied content can used in the browser using the below js snippet
navigator.clipboard.readText()
    .then((e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err)
    })

NOTE:

Given that these deal with promises, you'll need to execute the js asynchronously. You can read about in the answer posted here
You'll need to add the clipboard capability of the browser you are working with
You'll need to put focus on an input element in order to use the clipboard APIs (this is prevented in the browsers for security purposes)

